# jquery .each (2nd line) add background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list showing in `html` like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Now, I added for each 2nd line a background color using this jquery:

```
$("ul li").each(function(index) {

    if (index % 2 == 0) {

        $(this).addClass("second-line");

    }

});
```

BUT, each list item can be filtered to just view for the user currently logged in. So some lines will be hidden if I would filter the list. But after filtering the list, the `jQuery` to make each 2nd line is messed up.

How can I make that work?

I tried this:

```
$(".button").click(function() {

    $("ul li").each(function(index) {

        var uid = $(this).attr("data-uid");
        var tuid = $(this).attr("data-tuid");

        if (uid != tuid) {

            $(this).hide(500);

        }

    });

    $("ul li").each(function(index) {

        if (index % 2 != 0) {

            $(this).removeClass("second-line");

        }

    });

});
```

But no success.

Comment: Why you dont only select 2nd line ?

Comment: You can do this without js; try using `li:nth-child(2n)`

Comment: I know I can use the css selector, but when clicked on a button my page doesn't refresh, so the css can't update..

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$( "ul li:nth-child(2)" ).addClass("second-line");` for the second elemnt.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the :odd selector. With this one, you can select all the odd items (= 2nd, 4th,...). More info here: https://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/

Answer (score 0):

you can make it with css.

like:

```
ul:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #00ffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

may this will work for you

```
 $("ul li:even").each(function(index) {



            $(this).removeClass("second-line");



    });
```

[jquery even](https://api.jquery.com/even-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will helps you

```css
ul li:nth-child(even) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```